# Cocoapods .podspec cannot find include headers

Tags: cocoapods, static-libraries, podspec

I have a Objective-C iOS library that uses and ships a third party static C lib. One of my Objective-C source file imports that library using

```
#import <teamspeak/public_errors.h>
```

but the generated xcode target by Cocoapods cannot find that header.

This is the simplified structure of my folders

[image]

and this is my `.podspec` file

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name             = 'TSKit'
  spec.version          = '0.1.0'
  spec.summary          = 'An iOS TeamSpeak client'

  spec.description      = <<-DESC
  TSKit is a Objective-C wrapper around the C TeamSpeak client library.
                       DESC

  spec.homepage         = 'https://github.com/JanC/TSKit'
  spec.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  spec.author           = { 'Jan Chaloupecky' => 'jan.chaloupecky@gmail.com' }
  spec.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/JanC/TSKit.git', :tag => spec.version.to_s }
  
  spec.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

  spec.frameworks = 'AVFoundation', 'AudioToolbox'

  spec.source_files = 'TSKit/Classes/**/*'
  
  spec.ios.vendored_library = 'TSKit/lib/libts3client.a'
  spec.libraries            = "ts3client", 'c++'

  spec.preserve_paths = 'TSKit/include/**' 
  
  # spec.header_dir          = "TSKit/include"
  # spec.header_mappings_dir = 'TSKit/include'

  spec.pod_target_xcconfig  =  {"HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "$(PODS_ROOT)/#{spec.name}/include/**"}

end
```

As you can see, I tried using both `spec.header_dir`  and `spec.header_mappings_dir` without any luck.

`pod lib lint` fails:

```
 -> TSKit (0.1.0)
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file. (in target 'App')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  10:9: fatal error: 'teamspeak/public_errors.h' file not found
```

You can find a sample project here(be sure to checkoung the `so-question` branch)

https://github.com/JanC/TSKit/tree/so-question

Answer (score 0):

`spec.header_mappings_dir = 'TSKit/include/**/*.h'` should cause cocoapods to recursively traverse the subfolder `teamspeak` and find the `public_error.h` header.